# Bayes Estimate for Mean Squared Loss in Uniform Prior

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, uniform-distribution, umvue, uninformative-prior

Can some one please help me out in Verifying if my prior distribution is uniform then will my Bayes estimate will always be MLE or UMVUE?
If $X_i$ follow iid $N(\theta,1)$ and prior distribution of $\theta$ is $\frac{1}{R}$ then in that case Bayes Estimate=MLE=UMVUE=mean of given observation. But should it be the case always?

Answer (score 0):

The Bayes estimator associated with the mean squared error loss
$$L(\delta,\theta)=||\theta-\delta||^2$$
is the posterior mean, $\mathbb E^\pi[\theta|D]$, if $D$ denotes the data. Under a flat prior, assuming the likelihood $\ell(\theta|D)$ is integrable in $\theta$, it writes
$$\mathbb E^\pi[\theta|D]=\int\theta\ell(\theta|D)\text d\theta\Big/\int\ell(\theta|D)\text d\theta$$
Since this expectation is not *equivariant* under transforms other than linear ones, i.e.,$$\mathbb E^\pi[\varphi(\theta)|D]\ne\varphi\left(\mathbb E^\pi[\theta|D]\right)$$
the posterior mean estimator cannot be the MLE in the overwhelming majority of parameterisations of the model (since the MLE is *equivariant*). Note that the natural association of MLE's with Bayes estimators is to see them as MAP estimators (which are [arguably](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/2009/09/12/map-estimators-are-not-truly-bayesian-estimators/) *not* Bayes estimators).

Similarly, since proper Bayes estimators are *always* biased, they cannot be UMVUE. Improper versions can may be unbiased, for some specific parameterisations of the model, but again will not be in the overwhelming majority of parameterisations of the model. It may be that, in the [very exclusive circle of estimations problems where an UMVUE does exist](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/2018/01/18/best-unbiased-estimators/), it can be expressed as a generalised Bayes estimator, but I am not aware of such a result.

Comment: thanks a lot.That helps.

Comment: If @Xi'an's answer helped you, please upvote it and accept the same by clicking the tick alongside the post.